# how can I convert spatvector to spatialpolygonDataframe or extract raster values with terra pakages?

Tags: terra

I try to extract raster values from vector data in spatvector format but the console returns an error message.
i used  the rgdal package to import my vector files in spatialpolygonDataframe format. but rgdal is no longer available on r.
how can i import my shp files in spatialpolygonDataframe format? the spatvector format is giving me problems extracting raster values[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Nyd.png)

update r version 4.3.2
update packages raster, terra, sf

Comment: You are mixing up packages. Do not use the "raster" package, only "terra" and extract from a `SpatRaster` not a `RasterStack`. See `?terra::extract`